# Avoid rerender of ListHeaderComponent for each item in list

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

In my React Native Function component I use [Expo FlatList](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/react-native/flatlist) to display many images from the Google firebase storage.

[image: My Component Screen]

In doing so, I noticed that the
[ListHeaderComponent](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/react-native/flatlist/#listheadercomponent) is rendered for each individual event.

```
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
Storage loaded:
"1645357882600"
######################################
and so on...
```

Since I also query data from the Local Sotrage in the `ListHeaderComponent`, this leads to a heavy load.

Does anyone have an idea how I can avoid the rerendering the `ListHeaderComponent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is a good or the right solution, but it works for me an feels like a workaround.

In the ListHeaderComponent create a useEffect and bind this to one State using the Array.

```
useEffect(() => { getCurrentEvent() }, [isActive]);
```